# Parse JSON data using Asihttprequest and the Json framework for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, json, asihttprequest, json-framework

I've been learning how to parse JSON using the JSON framework and ASIHTTPRequest for iOS. I've tested using twitter feeds and also a custom feed through a community tutorial. All is going well.

I then thought I'll test using the Microsoft Odata Service for Northwind db. You can view the json results here:

[http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products%281%29?$format=json](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products%281%29?%24format=json)

Now I've struggling to work out how to parse just the product name. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**On my requestFinished i have this**:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];

    //find key in dictionary
    NSArray *keys = [responseDict allKeys];

    NSString *productName = [responseDict valueForKey:@"ProductName"];
    NSLog(@"%@",productName);
}
```

In the log I have null.

If I change the valueforKey to `@"d"` I get the whole of the payload but I just want the productName.

The service URL I am using is:

[http://servers.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products(1)?$format=json](http://servers.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products%281%29?%24format=json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the link you have provided](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products%281%29?%24format=json), your JSON has the following format:

```
{
  "d": {
    ...
    "ProductName": "Chai",
    ...
  }
}
```

At the top level, you only have one key: `"d"`. If you do this:

```
NSString *productName = [responseDict valueForKey:@"ProductName"];
```

It will return `nil`. You need to get deeper in the hierarchy:

```
NSDictionary *d = [responseDict valueForKey:@"d"];
NSString *productName = [d valueForKey:@"ProductName"];
```

Or simply:

```
NSString *productName = [responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"d.ProductName"];
```

Comment: Spot on. This wrapping of the response inside an outer level 'd' seems to be a common .net / Microsoft thing.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much  yeah wrapping in the d is strange o well.

Comment: Quick updadte - I've switched to using the JSONkit and the above gives me null. any ideas?

Comment: I've checked that my json is being returned correctly by using a LOG statement all looks good as before but I dont get the follows - the json is the same as above

Comment: ok got it - i had to change it to this with jsonkit NSString *productName = [responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"d.results.ProductName"];